# Can TableSort honor form rebuilds?

Tags: forms

I have a `Form` route in a site I am working on that is doing an `entityQuery` and displaying tabular data with some form elements to provide filtering, but without paging.  For various reasons I can't use Views to do this; a lot of the table cells are complex calculations and don't lend themselves to a proper plugin.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->tableSort($headers)
  ->condition('type','foo')
  ->condition('status', Node::PUBLISHED);

if ($filters) {
  // Add more conditions.
}

$results = $query->execute();
```

and then I essentially just have

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
}

public function resetForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setRebuild(FALSE);
}
```

as my form handlers.

The table sorting works great.  My form and filters work great.

Here's my problem.  When a user clicks on a table header, it is essentially a link to the page w/ a `GET` query with the sort selection and bypasses the form submission process.  When this happens, the filters get reset.  Can `TableSort` play nicely and do a proper form submission, or do I need to cookie the form state and do the rebuild manually (as needed).

Comment: You could add a few lines of JS to listen for the header click, add the sort param to the form action, then submit the form as a normal POST?

Comment: `Can TableSort play nicely and do a proper form submission` are you saying that if you remove `->tableSort($headers)` the rebuild works as expected?

Comment: @Clive, since Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Table is a FormElement it should be able to produce such POST links on its own. Looks to me like this is a valid bug report or feature request.

Comment: @4k4 Views exposed filters + table output work together, but those are all GET forms, and the exposed filters and table are different `<form>` elements. So, I think this is just a problem with my form and not a bug,

Comment: Now the table sort feature is added in a preprocess hook and it doesn't behave differently than a render element. As a form element preparing the clickable headers should probably start in a #process callback.